# Higher Order Derivatives and Directional Derivatives Formula

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

Let $E,F$ be Banach spaces, $X$ open in $E^n$ and $f\colon X\to F$ be differentiable in $x_0\in X$. We know that for $v\in E^n\setminus\{0\}$ the directional derivative
$$ \partial_v f(x_0) = \lim_{t\to 0}\frac{f(x_0+tv)-f(x_0)}{t}$$ exists and that $\partial_vf(x_0) =\partial f(x_0)v$. Does this propagate to higher order derivatives?

Let $f$ be twice differentiable in $x_0$. I am interested in if it is true that $$\partial^2f(x_0)(h,k) = \partial_k\partial_hf(x_0) = \partial(\partial f(\cdot)h)(x)k,\quad h,k\in E^n$$ (I think it is) and how I would prove it.

Comment: Are you familiar with the Hessian matrix $\mathsf D^2 f$, representing in the canonical basis the action of the second differential operator of a sufficiently regular real function $f$ defined over Euclidean space? Given two vectors $\mathbf h,\mathbf k \in \mathbb R^n$, we may certainly write
$$\frac{\partial^2}{\partial \mathbf h \partial \mathbf k} f(\mathbf x_0) = \mathbf h^\top \mathsf D^2f(\mathbf x_0) \mathbf k = \sum_{i,j=1}^n \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_i\partial x_j}(\mathbf x_0) h_ik_j. $$

Comment: @giobrach Yes, I am familiar. My question follows from your last equation in your special case, still it doesn't help me much because I am interested in a coordinate-free reasoning as $E$ could be multi-dimensional.